# Looping through JSON and insert data to Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, json

Below is how i have my data at the moment. How would i achieve in postgres with Postgresql to get all those "class_name" and "id" values and store them on their own rows in the database. I can store the data as JSON or JSONB, that doesnt matter but im having trouble looping through all the cases and getting all the values.

I have tried json_each and combination of jsonb_query_path and json_array_elements but only have managed to get only the first case in each suite.

Would appreciate any help here and i would prefer to do this with postgresql instead of python

```
 {
  "duration" : 6109.1104,
  "failCount" : 0,
  "passCount" : 4389,
  "skipCount" : 0,
  "suites" : [
    {
    "cases" : [
      {
        "class_name": "testname1",
        "id": 231
      },
      {
        "class_name": "testname2",
         "id": 233
      }
    ],
    "duration" : 0.012,
    "id" : null,
    "name" : "EventTest",
    "stderr" : null,
    "stdout" : null,
    "timestamp" : null
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine two jsonb_array_elements() calls:

```
select c.cases ->> 'id' as id,
       c.cases ->> 'class_name' as class_name
from the_table
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(the_column -> 'suites') as s(suite)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(s.suite -> 'cases') as c(cases);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3442d3dc4cf9e3335356c42eda1076b2)

Comment: This seems like a solution that I'd like to use but it results me with error: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" when i want to insert the data into column on my table

Comment: @LauriHuhta: then you are not using the query in my answer.

Comment: Here is my query:
INSERT INTO {TEST_RESULT_TABLE}(
    class_name
)
SELECT(
    c.cases ->> 'className' AS class_name
)
FROM
    {staging_t}
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'suites') AS s(suite)
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(s.suite -> 'cases') AS c(cases)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the column expression `( c.cases ->> 'className' AS class_name ) ` should be `c.cases ->> 'className' AS class_name`

Comment: Ah such a foolish mistake. Thank you so much! You were a huge help and answered fast!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have 2 tables;

```
create table class_table (
  id integer,
  class_name text 
);

create table json_table(
  id serial primary key,
  data jsonb not null
);
```

Here is the query;

```
select 
  (jsonb_populate_record(
        null::class_table, 
      jsonb_path_query(t.data, '$.suites[*].cases[*]')
    )).*
from json_table t
```

- `(..).*` Part converts record into fields
- `json(b)_populate_record`
  expands the object in json(b) to a row whose columns match the record
  type (`class_table`)
- And finally `json(b)_path_query` gets all items returned by the path (`'$.suites[*].cases[*]'`)

expected result:

```
| id  | class_name |
| --- | ---------- |
| 231 | testname1  |
| 233 | testname2  |
```